# How to start a project using meteor.js and vue.js

Tags: javascript, meteor, vue.js

I am new in meteor.js. I want to build a project using meteor.js and vue.js. but I can't find the proper way to manage files in meteor.js. So can anyone help me to find demo project or video link?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vsqBue6bM9Q ?

Answer (score 0):

There are some scaffolding projects already on this.

This is a very nice and maintained set of packages for Meteor+Vue. 
https://github.com/meteor-vue/vue-meteor

I recommend you starting with an already scaffolding example, so you can see how is it used Meteor Collections, Meteor Publications/Subscriptions, and Vuex (not necessarily for a small app, but as soon as you start to worry about a centralised App State manager, it is very helpful).

https://github.com/Akryum/meteor-vue2-example

I am experimenting with this nowadays, if you need any more help ping! Wishing some native integration of MeteorJS and VueJS soon.

cheers.